# Why size of extern variables is 0 in ELF?

Tags: c, linker, elf

Extern declarations of variables in a c program result in size 0 in ELF. Why isn't actual size stored in ELF when known? For cases like incomplete arrays I understand there is no size information but for other cases it should be possible to store size.

I tried some simple codes and verified in ELF size emitted is zero.

```c
// file1.c

extern int var;
int main()
{
    var = 2;
}
```

```c
// file 2.c
long long int var = 8;
```

```sh
gcc -c file1.c
readelf -s file1.o
...
9: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND var
...
```

```sh
gcc -c file2.c
readelf -s file2.o
...
7: 0000000000000000     8 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 var
...
```

If size of var was stored as 4 in file1.o, linker can actually detect potential mismatch due to size when linking with file2.o.

So why isn't size emitted as it can help catch some subtle issues like this?

Comment: size is a poor substitute for type checking. A `long long` and `double` often have the same size, 8.  Size checking would not catch `extern long long x` being defined as `double x`.

Comment: Good point on the incomplete arrays! Was going to write about it but then noticed you had mentioned it already.

Comment: @kaz, yes size isn't sufficient in cases like you mentioned but could have been better than nothing. Holding types in object files may not be possible always. I also found out if I enable LTO, it catches such mismatches as with -flto type information is stored and mismatch is detected and warning is emitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `file1`, `var` is just a placeholder. It will not occupy any memory. The extern identifier is to indicate to the compiler and the linker that the variable `var` is stored elsewhere.

It would be wrong to have two storage locations for the single variable `var` as you have suggested.

It is a quirk of the C language that you can define a different type for extern variable and a different type for the underlying global variable as you have done in your example. This is one of the reasons that we have static analysis tools.

Comment: Though there is the common extension that merges the undefined symbols with defined.